# kendo ui grid- prevent undoing where value is not valid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I use keno-ui grid with validation-rules.

The kendo-ui grid validation behavior is, the when user update value of any field, and the value is not valid, he get tooltip with validation-message, ant connot go out from field without changing value to a valid value.

If he presses escape/enter - he can go out, but- the updating lost, and the old value- return.
I want that when user input in-valid value, so:

1. He gets validation-message-tooltip
2. He can leave the field by enter/escape but the new value is not removed, the old value- not returns.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code so far? I guess you could use some JavaScript to set fields of HTML. Example here (Try type like "ö" or space or something.):

```js
document.getElementById("name").onkeyup = function(){;
  if(document.getElementById("name").value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/g) === null){
    document.getElementById("errorName").className = "show";
    document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "<span id='alert'>&nbsp;!</span>Please only use english letters";
    }
  else{
    document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("errorName").className = "";
  }
};
```

```css
#errorName{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#alert{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.show{
  -webkit-animation: show 1s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes show{
  0% {background-color: gray;}
  100% {width: 200px;background-color: white;}
}
```

```html
<!--Form... bla bla bla-->
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" /><span id="errorName"></span>
<!--Bla bla bla-->
```

Comment: Thank you very match for the good answer, but I want to use default validation of kendo, and not do it by mySelf. I only want to change its behavior

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Well, then I shouldn't be here. See you then :/